# multiprocessing to make request in Python

Tags: python

I want to test a website's response speed, so I write like this:

```
import urllib.request as request
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Value

def response_test(lock, count, time1, time2):
    t1 = time.time()
    r = request.urlopen('http://localhost/json/threads')
    t2 = time.time()
    c = r.read()
    t3 = time.time()
    lock.acquire()
    try:
        time1.value += t2-t1
        time2.value += t3-t2
        count.value += 1
        if count.value == 4:
            print(time1.value / 4, time2.value / 4)
    finally:
        lock.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()
    count = Value('i', 0)
    time1 = Value('d', 0.0)
    time2 = Value('d', 0.0)
    for i in range(4):
        p = Process(target=response_test, args=(lock,count,time1,time2))
        p.start()
```

output: `0.5701152682304382 0.015613257884979248`
so it looks like take 0.5s to get a response. But without `multiprocessing`, just a simple loop:

```
def response_test():
    t1 = time.time()
    r = request.urlopen('http://localhost/json/threads')
    t2 = time.time()
    c = r.read()
    t3 = time.time()
    return (t2-t1, t3-t2)
```

do it the same times and calculate the average, I got `0.18742609024047852, 0.01562190055847168`. Why using `multiprocessing` is slower?

Comment: Did you run both tests multiple times to account for randomness? Is it possible that whatever server you're using only processes one request at a time in a queue?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Thanks! I think I use a development server which doesn't support multiprocess or multithread.

Comment: In that case if you fire off multiple requests at almost the exact same moment it is going to take longer in total, because some processes will be waiting while another processes request is being processed by the server.

Comment: Maybe the test works and your web server performs slower when 4 requests come at the same time? It should be at least 2 times slower with 4 simultaneous requests, which is close to what your numbers show.